# @ViewChild Accessing children is empty in ngAfterViewInit - Ionic5 - Angular6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Problem accessing the native `textarea` element within `ngAfterViewInit`

I have this `ElasticTextareaComponent` which grows in height if the user has multiple rows. The area is a simple `ion-textarea` in which the native textarea element needs to be accessed.

```
<ion-textarea #ionTxtArea
              placeholder='{{placeholder}}'
              [(ngModel)]="content"
              (ngModelChange)='onChange($event)'>
</ion-textarea>
```

In my `.ts` file I initialize the Child as
`@ViewChild('ionTxtArea', {static: false}) ionTxtArea: any;`

The Component implements `AfterViewInit` to be able to access `ngAfterViewInit`. And here comes the pain. The `textarea` is not available in this method. I figured out waiting 1 second makes everything accessable.

```
public ngAfterViewInit() {

    // undefined
    this.txtArea = this.ionTxtArea.el.querySelector('textarea');

    // working
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.txtArea = this.ionTxtArea.el.querySelector('textarea');
    })
}
```

How would I be able to access this without the 1 sec delay?

Comment: I am noticing the `static: false`. Are you using an `ngIf` or something similar in the surrounding code we are not seeing?

Comment: Sounds like there is an `*ngIf` somewhere in the tree that resolves during the timeout.

Comment: Changing static to true does not make a difference. No *ngIf is used since i'm currently just building the components without logic.

Comment: Then it is an implementation detail of `ion-textarea`. The real text-area is probably not immediately rendered, because that component itself might have an `ngIf`. Is it not possible to set the necessary attributes on the `ion-textarea` itself?

Comment: Your setTimeout **not** make 1 sec delay, only say to Angular, that after repaint all, check again to try find a querySelector and is perfect -even you can use in ngOnInit-. NOTE: The "static:true" is used when the component is always on screem (there' no under a *ngIf, e.g.) so Angular can check if exist or not. "static:false", make that Angular search the component each time the screen is repaint

Answer (score 0):

```
// Maybe something similar to this will work for you
@ViewChild() component:ionTextArea 
// set up an interval
let delay = interval(500);
// kick off interval set up subscription
let sub = delay.subscribe(time=>{
   //if component is there
   if(this.component){
    //set the txtArea
     this.txtArea = this.component.value;
    //unsubscribe
     sub.unsubscribe();
   }
})
```

You could also, if you don't want the delay code....set up an event service.

```
this.eventService.onTextAreaReady.subscribe(
  (component)=>{ //component is now ready to use.}
)
```

Create a new service ng c s eventservice

[image]

Just make sure to import the EventServive and pass it in via the constructor

```
constructor(private eventService:EventService){
   //hook up subscription
   this.eventService.onTextAreaReady.subscribe(
  (component)=>{ //component is now ready to use.}
)}
```

Then in the ion component..

```
afterViewInit(){
  this.eventService.componentReadyEvent.emit();
}
```

Note there are other reasons for the delay, such as an iterative rendering section of the code where the performance of the app is being stressed.  Finding those issue requires digging into the rendering of the component via running performance traces.

Comment: The question explicitely states: _How would I be able to access this without the 1 sec delay?_

Comment: Ok changed the answer. The code clearly shows no delay via *ngIf or any other method that we can see.  This means that it's a render lag.  The only way to do this without a delay is to set up an eventemitter afterViewInit, but it would either need to be static or contained in another way such as a global event service.

Comment: Funny, but I suspect it means: _how can I do this without a delay._

Comment: Fair enough I gave additional eventService suggestion too.

Comment: Exactly there is no *ngIf and the 1 sec delay is just a guessed value by me. I don't know if slower user devices will take longer than 1 sec. Ideally something like "onRenderComplete" for the `ion-textarea`. I will give this a try later .